# Infimum of the union of 3 sets under some restriction

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, real-numbers

I was given the following to solve- [image]

At first I assumed that I would have to solve it by breaking up and showing that for each set (A, B and my arbitrary set D) that the infimum was as proven by also using the theorem-

If $x < 0$ then $inf(xA)$ and $sup(xA)$ $= x Sup(A)$ and $x inf(A)$ respectively.

Therefore, the inequality for T and B would be reversed.

Also, I know that for the union of 2 sets, $A$ and $B$, then $SupS$ $= Sup A + SupB$, and that c is clearly the union set A and B along with elements of C (and if this works for sup, it should hold for inf).

I have tried a proof but I strongly feel that it is incorrect. (And as a result, I did not complete it)  I would appreciate some guidance to the correct answer as well as some guided explanations of what I should do, and how to approach this question.

Also, I am wondering that since the inequalities for both T and B are all $\geq$ to $0$, if I should then include in the proof the assumption that the values $ a_{1}S $ and $a_{2}T$ should then be equal to $0$.

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Start with any x in A and y in B. Show that $a_1 x$ is at least as large as $a_1 S$ and $a_2 y$ is at least as large as $a_2 T$. Then, you can show $a_1 x+a_2 y+a_3$ is at least as large as $a_1 S+a_2 T+a_3$. That shows $a_1 S+a_2 T+a_3$ is a lower bound. To show that it is the inf, you will need to find an $x$ close enough to $S$ and a $y$ close enough to $T$ to guarantee that $a_1 x+a_2 y+a_3$ is as close as I want to the supposed inf. The existence of those is guaranteed by the assumptions on S and T.

Comment: Hi, im reading what you said and whilst I think I understand, I still feel a bit unsure- can you explain some more ? what do you mean by showing $a_1$x is as large s $a_1$S ? wouldn't it be as small as since we are talking about infimum ?

Comment: $x \le S \implies a_1x \ge a_1S$

Comment: Oh, okay thank you.